# CSS - Odd "zoomed in" background picture for mobile

Tags: css

I released my website and noticed that the "contact me" background picture in mobile users in zoomed in excessively. On the PC, it looks good, but in a mobile interface, it's another story.

[Website](http://www.mohanadarafe.io)

[Zoomed in background](https://gyazo.com/878854e80a0297547f5586f8fd795f8e)

CSS:

```
#contact{
background: url('../img/contactBg.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position:left;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

@media(max-width: 1024px) {
      #contact{
        background-position: 45%;
        background-size: cover;
      } 
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your css and your website looks fine as well. What device are you using?

Comment: @AbdulSadikYalcin open it with your iphone you will see

Comment: I'm an android user and can't see an issue.

Comment: can you take a screenshot and show me please?

Comment: Here you go: https://imgur.com/a/0cadbrR

Comment: Woa that's weird, I'll try to see why it works well for you but not iPhone users. May I ask which Android phone you have?

Comment: You may be cached mate. Try incognito or different browser on your phone. Huawei P20 Pro.